# Leaflet : How to update polyline ? Live Tracking

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, google-maps-api, php, jquery

```
        var ColorVar = '#bd0026'; 
        var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(polyList, {
        color:ColorVar,
        weight: 8,
        opacity:0.8,
        smoothFactor: 1
        } 
        );
        focusId.addLayer(firstpolyline);  
        }
```

On the page load , i have using the above code after that i want to update the polyline based on the new data without page refreshing for Live Tracking Concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is what you are after:

```
// get data using ajax. Might be triggered by a button, some other user interaction, or polling remote tracking data
$.get(url, {params}, function(response, {
   // on success, remove the old polyline
   focusId.removeLayer(firstpolyline); 

   // refresh the Polyline
   polylist = response.polylist;
   var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(polyList, {...} );

   // then add the new polyline back to the map 
   focusId.addLayer(firstpolyline);
})
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer.  Below code worked.

var latLngs =L.latLng(lPolylat, lPolylng);
polylineLive.addLatLng(latLngs);

Comment: Is it possible get directions on leaflet ? . I have a marker (arrow image) now i want to change the marker position based on co-ordinates.

Thanks

Comment: there are several leaflet plugins for routing, check out: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine

Answer (score 0):

For ajax receiving @toms has great answer already.

For redrawing polyline, probably addLatLng will suit your need.
Just do `polyline = L.polyline([]).addTo(map);` and `polyline.addLatLng([x, y]);` when new data comes.