# Create a PostGIS table through HTML, PHP and the GeoServer REST API through a specific script

Tags: php

I need to create a HTML page that allows for creating a new PostGIS table in a specific database, through the GeoServer API. So I'm specifically interested in the Creating a PostGIS table part of this tutorial

I'm trying to create a HTML form (post) for that PHP script but I don't know how to start... I already have my Apache, Geoserver+Tomcat, PHP running but I'm a bit lost for that...  Does this PHP code in the link work with a HTML form, prompting for the user to fill a form with $table, $geometry?

http://cnokello.blogspot.com/2012/09/geoserver-rest-api-with-php.html

In particular,  I don't know where to put the lines at the bottom and beginning of the explanation page. Should they be on a separate page?

```
define("GEOSERVER_REST_HOST", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/");
define("GEOSERVER_USER", "username:password");
```

and

```
$data = An array with the following elements, at a minimum:
$data['transactType'] = "CREATE_POSTGIS_TABLE"
$data['contentType'] = "Content-type: text/xml"
$data['store'] = $t, details of the store to be created, which can be as shown below:
```

and:

```
$t = "<featureType>";
$t .= "<name>".$table."</name>";
$t .= "<nativeName>".$table."</nativeName>";
$t .= "<title>".$table."</title>";
$t .= "<srs>EPSG:4326</srs>";
$t .= "<attributes>";
$t .= "<attribute>";
$t .= "<name>the_geom</name>";
$t .= "<binding>com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.".$geometry."</binding>";
$t .= "</attribute>";
$t .= "<attribute>";
$t .= "<name>description</name>";
$t .= "<binding>java.lang.String</binding>";
$t .= "</attribute>";
$t .= "<attribute>";
$t .= "<name>timestamp</name>";
$t .= "<binding>java.util.Date</binding>";
$t .= "</attribute>";
$t .= "</attributes>";
$t .= "</featureType>";
```

Comment: It's very poor security design to permit table creation through a web service, leaving you vulnerable to a denial of service attack.

Comment: @Vince for the moment, it's for the purpose of learning - then I will learn about authentifications, which are even more tricky for me

Comment: It's not about authentication. Table creation should simply NOT be permitted. Ever. Adding rows is risky enough (and only with a user which does not have create table permission, not the owner).

Comment: @Vince but basically when you want to allow a user to draw some features on an empty online map on his smartphone , to easily find it back home when he starts Qgis, a new table in Postgis isn't what you need?  - or he'll have to save a geojson on his smartphone and copy it after

Comment: New table creation is NOT the way to accomplish that. It *is* the way to destroy your database by filling it with an unending pile of tables that may never be accessed again.

Comment: is adding data to postgis feasible and a solution? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197708/automatically-refresh-my-wfs-layer-in-leaflet-when-adding-data-in-postgis @Vince